# Pool table light

Tags: electrical, ground

I have a pool table light (with a pull chain) that comes ready to be hard wired; however, I want to connect the light’s wires to a plug (using connectors for this purpose). I have connected the ribbed wire side with the black wire of the plug and the non-ribbed side of the wire coming from the light to the plug’s white wire. This will allow me to plug the light into a standard outlet (in the ceiling of a garage).

The problem I have is, the light fixture has a bare copper (ground I assume) wire. I am not sure what to do with it? The fixture will hang from the ceiling with chain links. I have threaded the fixture’s electrical wires up through the chain links. What do I do with the bare ground wire? Do I thread it also through the chain links? If so, what do I connect it to? If not, what do I do with it?

[image]

Comment: moved image inline.

Comment: Why **not** hardwire it? It is very simple to convert a ceiling receptacle for hardwiring a light.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I think a reasonable assumption is there is no ceiling box and the intent is to use a wall outlet.

Comment: What plug did you buy?

Comment: @jay613 so run a long lamp cord up to the ceiling, across, and down to an outlet?

Comment: @Huesmann yes, that is my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the entire cable with a three-wire lamp cord including ground, and buy a three-prong plug for it.

[image]

Hopefully you can easily get access to the clam-shaped box that the wires enter at the top of the lamp, and hopefully in there the existing wire is joined to wires from the three bulbs. That would make this relatively easy.  Pay attention to how strain relief is provided to the existing cable and replicate that with your new one.

Answer (score 1):

Whoa!  Few issues here. First, the ribbed  wire (in the zip cord) is the neutral white wire. The smooth wire is the black hot wire. The batter ground wire should be threaded thru the chain with the zip cord. This type of ground is used on chain suspended fixtures to improve the grounding path thru the chain. Chain links do not always make a secure electrical connection to the next link for fault current. Three bare wire does not either, butt does greatly improve the problem. It must be connected to the grounding conductor at junction box.  Hard wiring is your best solution, however getting a 3 prong plug will work. Remember RIBBED white is neutral (silver screws) smooth is line (brass/gold screws) and bare wire is ground (green screw)